# How to show products with a specific attribute?

Tags: collection, products, product-collection

I have this code:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        // add sorting to collection optional
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('a_pecas_assinadas', array('eq' => 'Yes'))
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
   echo $_product->getId().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getName().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getProductUrl().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getPrice().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getSpecialPrice().'</br>';
   echo $_product->getImage().'</br>';
}
```

I created the **a_pecas_assinadas** attribute with **yes/no** type and I need to get a **foreach** which selects products that belong to this attribute group.

If I remove the attribute, the **foreach** work but if I put the attribute, the **foreach** crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing filtering wrong:

```
      $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
           // add sorting to collection optional
           ->addAttributeToFilter('a_pecas_assinadas', array('eq' => 1)) //1 is true 0 is false
           ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
           //->load()
           ;
```

Yes/No is boolean type and in database it is saved as 1 for Yes and 0 for No.

Now foreach should work.

Comment: Lighter version: `addAttributeToFilter('a_pecas_assinadas', 1)`